# Pocket Academy - How do I pick a good event planner?

Tags: ios, pocket-academy

When the yearly event comes up, I have to pick a student to plan it. The interface shows me the basic stats of each student, but nowhere does it explain which stats might contribute to success.

I assume popularity plays a role, since the "planning" consists of talking to the other students and convincing them to participate. I also thought that other stats might make a difference, depending on the event (e.g. athleticism for a baseball event). However, I don't have any actual evidence to confirm or deny these hypotheses.

So, what makes a student a good event planner?

Comment: It appears that the other tag(s) you've used were removed because this was the only question using them. Can you please edit the game name into the question, instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this site](http://kairospot.net/pocket-academy-guide) (registration required):

- Leader nature - Seems to improve the amount of research points that are generated during the event
- High popularity - Increases the number of students the organizer will talk to in the halls
- High number of friends - Increases the likelihood of other students participating in the event after talking to the organizer.
- Not in a couple - Students in couples will talk to each other more often, which will decrease the number of people the organizer is able to talk to about the event.